# with python3 need to Draw a count plot to show the number of each type of crime discovered each year

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

i need to Draw a count plot to show the number of each type of crime  discovered each year [some columns from csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTvZH.png) 
i have 2 columns will make process  only on it (primary type and date )
so any help to can implement in python

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
df=pd.read_csv('FileName.csv')
df1 = df[['ColumnName1','ColumnName2']]
print(df1)
plt.xlabel('ColumnName1')
plt.ylabel('ColumnName2')
a=plt.bar(df1['ColumnName1'], df1['ColumnName2']) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: df2 = df1[['primary type','date']] in this line i have this error


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-458f0f1ad9ce> in <module>()
----> 1 df2 = df1 (['primary type','date'])

NameError: name 'df1' is not defined

Comment: did u define  df1? and df2?